# JQuery Draggable DIV in Draggable LI move to new DIV or create new DIV

Tags: jquery, dynamic, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, destroy

I'm new to js and jquery, and it's hard for me to code this task:

I have a big DIV (.pins_dragger) element, it is fixed on layout. DIV.pins_dragger contains some other DIVS (.group) which are Draggable. DIV.group contains UL with LI. 
Each LI contains only one DIV(.pin).

The task:

1. Every DIV.pin shall be freely draggable inside DIV.group AND every DIV.pin can be freely moved to any other DIV.group.
2. If DIV.pin goes out of it's DIV.group and locates outside another DIV.group (on a free space of DIV.pins_dragger), then it creates new DIV.group at this location.
3. If DIV.pin is the last one in DIV.group and moves out to another div.group then this Div.group destroys. While dragging on a free space, the parent DIV.group does not destroy, just drags alongside with child.

http://jsfiddle.net/dVyBm/3/

```
<div class="pins_dragger">
  <div class="group" id="group_1">
   <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
       <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">1</div></li>
       <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">2</div></li>
       <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">3</div></li>
       <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">4</div></li>
       <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">5</div></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="group" id="group_2">
   <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue">
        <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">1</div></li>
        <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">2</div></li>
        <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">3</div></li>
        <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">4</div></li>
        <li><div class="ui-widget-content pin">5</div></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="group" id="group_3"> 
   <ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
   </ul>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

The Idea can be shown in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VGUS2/

Comment: I don't know what functions i should use to handle move, drop and destroy with ajax requests.